# Why is Microwaved mac & cheese burnt where they touch?

Tags: everyday-life, home-experiment, resonance, microwaves, food

[image]

After reheating cold about 1.5 oz. of Annie's Mac & Cheese shells for 15 seconds on high power in the microwave, the mac & cheese was burnt black only at certain points where the pasta is touching each other. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

Comment: [Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCrtk-pyP0I) made a video with touching grapes in a microwave oven. Without having anything to actually back up my claim (I don't remember whether he said anything about things other than grapes), I suspect something similar is happening here. At any rate, it looks cool.

Comment: @Arthur: I might be wrong but from what I learned about cut half grapes in a microwave, was that that effect was kinda special due to the fruit sugar. So not sure if it is the same effect (but likely at least a similiar effect)

Comment: Same thing happens with sliced hot dogs.

Comment: That is not macaroni. As you say, they are shells, or conchiglie. As such, it is also not mac & cheese.

Comment: I'm "fairly confident" that the more esoteric explanations are overly so. Voltage is induced in closed  conducting paths. AT points of contact the resistance is high and the flowing current creates "i squared R" heating. (Power dissipation = current squared x resistance). This does not requires resonance, appropriate wavelength items or other RF interacting factors.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fine.  Macaroni product and cheese: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/21/139.110

Comment: @Tristan Interesting. It does appear that a governmental organisation in the USA (the FDA) has decided to lump loads of types of pasta into the category "macaroni products". This is, however, like "noodles" for not-noodles, purely an Americanism. I don't believe anybody else calls it that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are a ton of regulations on what various foods can be called.  Have a look: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/21/chapter-I/subchapter-B

Comment: @Tristan Again, that's specific to, and made up by, your country. General English language (and Italian, for that matter) does not accept the word "macaroni" for something that is not macaroni. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit who is General English and how can I meet him? In all seriousness, there are a host of other languages in which "macaroni" is the general term for pasta.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not that it's on topic: The word macaroni (or its closest linguistic relative) is just "pasta" in Slavic languages, including Russian. The case in Italian is also not a clear cut as you're making it sound, if you allow for various dialects where the meaning is more broad than you're suggesting. Greek, where the word originates, also uses it for "pasta". Same for several other languages around the world.

Comment: @gormadoc He's a good guy

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I get the same thing reheating some discs of glazed carrots.  And there are several videos of folks doing this intentionally with grapes.

An [article](https://www.pnas.org/content/116/10/4000) published last year in PNAS says this will happen with almost any pair of similarly-sized object with sufficient water.  The shape of the pairs appears to set up a resonance that concentrates the electric field at the point where they touch.  The higher intensity field there heats the surroundings and burns the food.

Comment: The reader should immediately search for images of the phenomenon. It is awesome.

Comment: I believe *size* was also important, but essentially, yes.

Comment: @Mindwin Any suggestion of what search terms to use? "`burnt microwave food`" doesn't exactly return these depictions.

Comment: @maxathousand "microwave grape plasma".

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCrtk-pyP0I) is a video which explains this phenomenon and briefly interviews the authors of the mentioned paper for more details.

Comment: @Mindwin Ah, it sounded like you knew a term to find examples with various foods, but perhaps this isn't a named phenomenon.

Comment: The important point being (quoting from another website): `If you see the plasma sort of escaping the point of contact between the two grapes and going to the top of the microwave, definitely turn it off, because it will melt a hole in the top of your microwave.`

Answer (score 10):

@BowlOfRed hit on it solidly. The noodles are acting as waveguides, because of their size and shape. Where they meet, a contiguous surface is created, but with a much higher resistivity, as it's a narrow point contact.

Based on [a table of refractive indexes](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/refractive-index-d_1264.html) and [a table of frequency/wavelength](http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/freq-wavelength.html), this effect would be especially effective when the total length of the joined area is at a resonance of the base wavelength of 3.54 inches (2.5ghz in air is 12cm, water is more refractive). So if they match in physical dimensions to 3.54 inches, 1.77 inches or 0.885 inches, the effect will channel a decent amount of energy. If that boundary between globules has a high resistance and carries a high amount of energy, it'll dissipate a lot of that energy as heat and light, potentially even creating plasma flashes as in the ideal natural example, the grapes mentioned by @BowlOfRed. Google "[Grape Plasma](https://www.google.com/search?q=grape%20plasma)," or just check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCrtk-pyP0I).

P.S. I don't know how big the Auntie Anne's shells are, but the curved concave shape is probably increasing their actual resonant size by something like 1.5 times. I'm not exactly sure how to work the formula on an irregular or non-ideal shape. Does that sound more like a match?

P.P.S. The YouTube dude captured some awesome shots of arrested plasma. He even talks some of the actual science of it. Trés magnifique!

Comment: Note that your table of refractive indices is for visible light. Refractive indices are different at different frequencies (an effect that's noticeable even within the regime of visible light, as we have rainbows). At the 2.5GHz scale, the refractive index of water is closer to 10.

Comment: These are not noodles. They are conchiglie (or "shells"). Noodles are long and thin.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, that bugs me too…  In the UK, at least, noodles != pasta.  (Different composition, shapes, and culinary uses.)  But according to Wiktionary, in the US ‘noodle’ has a wider meaning.

Comment: @gidds Interesting. (Horrifying :P)

Comment: Auntie Anne's are pretzels. The mac and cheese is Annie's ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm "fairly confident" that the more esoteric explanations are overly so.

Voltage is induced in closed  conducting paths in an RF field (here a complex E-M field with various nodes due to the cavity but that is not a major factor).

AT points of contact the resistance is high and the flowing current creates "i squared R" heating. (Power dissipation = current squared x resistance). This does not requires resonance, appropriate wavelength items or other RF interacting factors.

For a spectacular and odiferously vile effect

- Take an OLD and UNWANTED CD or DVD
  The CD / DVD will be utterly destroyed in the process.
- Stand it on a drinking glass or similar in the microwave oven.
- Set microwave to 3 to 5 seconds (longer is a mistake)
- Go
- Superb firestorm in miniature with "sheet lightning across the CD surface.
- Do not breathe the fumes. Conclude that it was fun but should have been dome outdoors. Wow!